# r ggplot - conditionally set aes element to NULL

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a wrapper function for ggplot to enable standard charts to be created with a single line of code.

One part of this is that in some cases the user will wish to set 'group' and 'color' aes elements, however in other cases they will not.

Is there a simple way of only having a 'group' or 'colour' aes element if the user passes one to the function, and to leave it blank otherwise?

I have tried simply setting these to to NULL, however this does not work, returning the following error.

```
 Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): x, y, group, colour
```

Comment: Have you looked at how others have solved the problem? Looking at the `qplot` code, or some of the functions from `GGally` would probably be a good place to start. It would also be helpful to see perhaps a simplified version of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `NULL`, try setting the aesthetic to `1`.